# StackOverFlowError when using MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I'm facing some problems to write unit tests for my controller. Unfortunately I don't use maven or gradle, I use Ant, so every dependency I need to download the jar and add manually. What I'm using to make tests is MockMvc, then I'm using the method standalonesetup to get the controller and build it. However when I first try to run it I get an exception

```
noSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.EmbeddedValueResolver.
```

To try to solve it I tried to download the spring-context, which contains this requestMappingHandlerMapping.EmbeddedValueResolver class. It solved the problem with noSuchMethodError, but now I'm getting StackOverFlow.Error

Here is an example of my classes

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

 @RequestMapping("/")
 @RequestBody
 public String message(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders requestHeader, @RequestParam String message)
 return "Something";
}
```

My test class is

```
public class controllerTest {
 
 private MockMvc mvc;

 //Point where I'm getting the error
 @Before
 public void setup(){
 this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaLoneSetup(new Controller()).build()
}
}
```

Can somebody help me to identify why I'm getting these errors?

Comment: I would strongly suggest to move of of Ant and start to use Maven (or Gradle) or at least introduce Ivy to have dependencies downloaded. The risk you face (and which is probably already the case) is that you are mixing jars from different Spring Versions which result in weird errors or use incompatible versions of jars (or supporting frameworks). Also your question states Spring Boot but are you really using Spring Boot?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately the company I work for uses a lot of old stuffs, there are many applications, there are some which use spring boot, and there are others which don't, so for those which ones that don't use we need to set all configuration beans by xml files, than they are able to "communicate" some how. But migrate to Maven or Gradle is a work in progress